# wordpress - no custom posts showing past page 1

Tags: php, wordpress

In my wordpress site, I added

```
<?php query_posts( 'post_type=sword'); ?>
```

above my loop, so my custom post type 'sword' now shows. Great, everything looks as it should, until I go to the next page - nothing. No custom posts past page one. Is this a pagination issue? And how do I solve this?

edit: if this involves much more than adding a one-liner, like I did for query_posts, I apologize for my ignorance. I would dig deeper if I only knew where to start

Comment: Can you try to post your complete relevant code ?

Answer (score 0):

Start digging by checking all the [loop examples here](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).